# Unable to bind it to my Grid to a Telerik OpenAccess DataSource

Tags: c#, .net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Im developing an application using ASP.MVC, Kendo and OpenAccess.

After created a custom property for an specific entity, I'm trying unsuccessfully to bind it to my Datasource and Grid.

Partial Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ErpMvc.OpenAccess
{
    public partial class Customer
    {
        public string CustomProperty
        {
            get
            {
                return "My Custom Property Text";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Service

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ErpMvc.OpenAccess;
using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions;
using Kendo.Mvc.UI;

namespace ErpMvc.Services
{
    public class CustomerService
    {
        public static IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers()
        {
            var dbContext = new EntitiesModel();

            return dbContext.Customers.Select(customer => new Customer
            {
                CustomerID = customer.CustomerID,
                FirstName = customer.FirstName,
                CustomProperty = customer.CustomProperty
            });

        }
    }
}
```

View

```
@model IEnumerable<ErpMvc.OpenAccess.Customer>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Customers")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.FirstName).Title("First Name");
        columns.Bound(c => c.CustomProperty).Title("Custom Property");
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Model(model => model.Id(customerID => customerID.CustomerID))
        .Read(read => read.Action("Customers_Read", "Customer"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("Customers_Update", "Customer"))
        .PageSize(50)
     )
)
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Customers_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    return Json(CustomerService.GetCustomers().ToDataSourceResult(request));
}
```

- Error messages I'm getting from VS
- Property or indexer 'CustomProperty' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
- After defined a "set{}" on my CustomProperty, this error messages was resolved but I started get this other one
- (...) If 'CustomProperty' is a property please add the FieldAlias or Storage attribute to it or declare it as a field's alias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use your OpenAccess objects in the view.

Try something like this (I've not tested this, just going by memory):

ViewModel:

Define a new class which contains all data the view requires.

```
namespace ErpMvc.ViewModel
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string CustomProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Service:

The service needs to retrieve the data using OpenAccess, then transfer this data to the view model.

```
public static IQueryable<Customer> GetCustomers()
{
    IQueryable<Customer> result = null;
    using(var dbContext = new EntitiesModel()) 
    {
        result = dbContext.Customers.Select(customer => new ViewModel.Customer
        {
            CustomerID = customer.CustomerID,
            FirstName = customer.FirstName,
            CustomProperty = customer.CustomProperty
        });
        return result;        
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Customers_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    return Json(CustomerService.GetCustomers().ToDataSourceResult(request));
}
```

View:

The model is not passed into the grid constructor, since you're using Read(). This also means you don't need to define the model at the top of the view.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ErpMvc.ViewModel.Customer>()
    .Name("Customers")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.FirstName).Title("First Name");
        columns.Bound(c => c.CustomProperty).Title("Custom Property");
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Model(model => model.Id(customerID => customerID.CustomerID))
        .Read(read => read.Action("Customers_Read", "Customer"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("Customers_Update", "Customer"))
        .PageSize(50)
     )
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Nic for having noticed my mistake and for your help. All the best buddy ;)

Comment: I feel that the answer posted by @Nicholas is forgetting that ToDataSourceResult() will apply filtering and paging.So if you call GetCustomers before calling ToDataSourceResult, you will hit the data with default query which will return all rows (say 10000 records)!!.

Comment: @MadaniBenghia Yep that's correct, I only showed how to get it working. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the approach suggested by @Nic is in the correct direction. From OpenAccess point of view, you will need to modify the query in the endpoint a little bit further. It should look similar to the following:

```
public static IEnumerable<ViewModel.Customer> GetCustomers()
{
    var dbContext = new EntitiesModel();

    return dbContext.Customers.Select(customer => new ViewModel.Customer
    {
        CustomerID = customer.CustomerID,
        FirstName = customer.FirstName,
    }).ToList();
}
```

The point is that the *customer* variable will not have its own CustomProperty.

I hope this helps.